# Confusing problem

Tags: education, puzzle

I got a problem in some books. Problem described like this. A boy borrowed `1000` rupees from one of his friend(X). And he borrowed `500` from another friend(Y). And he lost `1000` rupees from his hand on the way to shop. And he purchased for only `300` rupees. So he left only `200`. And he gave `100` each to those friends(`X` and `Y`). And he made an calculation.

1 . He have to give `900` to `X`

2 . He has to give `400` to `Y`

3 . He have product of `300`

So total `900+400+300 = 1600` . How that extra `100` comes from. Please help to solve.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96103/puzzle-where-did-the-extra-dollar-come-from

Comment: @EvangelosBampas Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that "to give" is not the same of "to have". So the correct balance should be
$$-900 (\mbox{back to $X$})-400 (\mbox{back to $Y$})+300 (\mbox{product})=-1000 (\mbox{lost}).$$

Comment: @Rahul K P Well done. If you are new here please take a few minutes for a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Am new to math but am very active in stackoverflow.