# Where is the logical error in this Math question? when it say where is the remaining 1?

Tags: puzzle

Three person buying something by **30**, each pay **10**, after a while, the owner making a discount of **-5**, but he realize that **5/2** is not good, so, he will return 1 for each, and gives the remaining **(2)** to his child, now:

1. each person paid 9: 3*9 = 27
2. Other remaining within owner's child: 2
3. SUM: 27 + 2 = 29!

My Question is: where is the remaining (1)? is there any logical error in this question?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/15524/264

Comment: sorry, but the story can be re-writted in different ways, so, It's not easy to find similar questions...

Comment: There is no error in this question.The question is framed in such a way to make the readers come to wrong conclusions.Out of the $ 27$ paid $25$ (payment) $ + 2$ (to the child) and the remaining $ 3 $ is given back to the $3$ persons.This makes the total$ 30. $

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a logical error. You should *subtract* 2 from 27, not *add* 2, to get 25, the final price. If you want to count the 30 paid initially, then it's just 10*3, nothing else.