# Where did two dollars go??

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

One of my school friends gave me this sum.Its basically a story formated into a sum

**STORY**

There were 3 friends.
They each gave 20 dollars to buy a radio.
They bought the radio for 60 dollar.
Later the shopkeeper saw that the cost of the radio was 50 dollar.
So he went to the friends to return 10 dollar.
On the way (of returning) he thought that 10 dollar can't be divided among 3 friends.
So he himself took 4 dollar  and rest 6 dollar was divided among three friends. 
thus each friend got 2 dollar.

**SUM**

Initially the shop keeper had 60 dollar.

And each friend finally gave 18*3=54 dollars
and the shopkeeper himself took 4 dollar.
thus total 58 dollar.

**THEN WHERE DID EXTRA  2 DOLLAR GO?????**

I tried it in many ways but still could not.
can any one help me out.

Comment: $\$54 - \$4 = \$50$ and $\$54+3\times \$2=\$60$

Comment: Essentially the same, but half price and many linked questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15524/riddle-simple-arithmetic-problem-illusion

Comment: When facing a word problem, the first part of the problem is to abstain from just arbitrarily combining all numbers given in the text by arbitrary mathematical operations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a total of 58 dollars. The shopkeeper is keeping 4 dollars, so instead of the friends paying \$50 for the radio they have paid \$54 after the shopkeeper returns some money.

Answer (score 1):

No you have interpreted wrongly see the shopkeeper has total $54$ dollars not $58$ so $54+2(each)=60$ each got $2$ again. What you have done is radio costs $54$ and top of that shopkeeper takes $4$ dollars which is wrong so two dollars went nowhere

Answer (score 1):

They should've payed 50 dollars, but paid 54, because as the shopkeeper has taken 4 dollars to themselves, the friends had to pay excess 4 dollars, so those 4 dollars are already included in those 54.