# Finding the difference of 100 rupees

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I borrowed money from 2 friends. One gave me 2000 and other gave me 500. 2000 rupees get lost by me and from 500 I shop for 300 rupees later give 100 rupees each to both.

- 2000 rupees left money is 1900
- 500 rupees left money is 400
- 1900+400=2300
- And 300 rupees of shopping
- Total 2300+300=2600

But i borrowed only 2500 so how the extra 100 rupees came?

Comment: This has nothing to do with general relativity.

Comment: You have borrowed 2300 rupees with which you have bought 300 rupees worth of merchandise, and lost 2000.  You should be subtracting and not adding in your last line.

Comment: Looks a lot like the famous dollar problem,perhaps a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15524/riddle-simple-arithmetic-problem-illusion)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Riddle (simple arithmetic problem/illusion)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15524/riddle-simple-arithmetic-problem-illusion)

Comment: "Total 2300+300=2600"  2300 is the money that was used/lost.  This includes the 300 rhuppes spent and the 2000 rhupees lost.  The 300 rhupees are the 300 spent.  Adding these together is not anything significant are meaningful.  It's just two arbitrary numbers added together.  It's like I'm 55 years old.  I was born in 1961.  I weigh 215 lbs.  1961 - 55 + 215 = 2121.  But it is only 2017.  Where did those extra 104 years come from?  The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: "You should be subtracting and not adding in your last line."  And the result will represent "Money gone - money spent = money lost";  not Total money borrowed.  To get total money borrowed you should add 200 (total money returned) instead of 300(total money spent).  Total borrowed= money gone + money returned.  The equation money gone + money spent = 2600 has no significance whatsoever.  (money gone *includes* money spent, so adding money spent to it a second time is ... meaningless.)

Answer (score 1):

Total liabilities/credit $2000+500-200$

Total expenses = lost $2000$+shopping cost

Answer (score 0):

There was a cartoon I once saw that I thought was funny.  It was a sign in front of a town that said:

Welcome to Quaintville:

Established: 1789
Population: 2312
Elevation: 67
.......
Total: 4168

The point is that just because you have a bunch of numbers that you can add together doesn't mean when you add them the result has any significance.

So let's look at what you've got:

- 2000-100 =1900. That is the money you lost/spent from friend 1
- 500-100 = 400.  That is the money you lost/spent form friend 2
- 1900 - 400=2300.  That is all the money you spent and lost.
- 300. That is all the money you spent.
- 2300 + 300 = 2600.  That is all the money you spent and all the money you lost and all the money you spent re-added to it.  This is two numbers added together for absolutely no reason whatsoever.  It is not the total money borrowed and there is no reason for you to think it should be.

Here's (one way) what you should do to get the money borrow.

- 100: Money returned to friend 1
- 100: Money returned to friend 2
- 100+100 = 200: Total money returned
- 2000 - 100= 1900: Money spent/lost from friend 1
- 500 - 100= 400: Money spent/lost from friend 2
- 1900 + 400 = 2300: Total money spent/lost
- 2300 + 200 = 2500: Total money involved = money spent/lost + money returned.